# ElasticSearch document with multiple categories

Tags: database, elasticsearch

I have a lot of documents that I want to make them searchable by ElasticSearch. These documents fit into several categories.

What it makes sense?

- Search all documents When accessing a category that fit the pattern.
- Manage own list of relevant documents.
- Can EleasticSearch create a list?

The full-text search in documents of certain categories also must be possible.

Sample Data:

```
{
    fulltext: "This is a Invoice from Project TestProject...",
    id: 1235456
}
```

Sample Categories:

```
[{
    name: "invoices",
    filter: {
        match: "invocie"
    }
},
{
    name: "testproject files",
    filter: {
        match: "testproject"
    }
}]
```

greets
philipp

Comment: Can you give a sample of the data you are thinking about? A category feels like a tag, each elastic index is sort of a list but each document can also contain a list of other items. So there are a lot of answers possible, but to give the right answer we need a bit more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a string field to your document type and store the category for each document there. Then you can filter on that field in your search queries to limit matches to specific categories.

Something like this for your document:

```
   {
        "fulltext": "This is a Invoice from Project TestProject...",
        "category": "Invoice"
    }
```

And to search for a document with the text "testproject" within the "invoice" category:

```
 GET /_search
    { "query":
    {
        "filtered": {
            "query":  { "match": { "fulltext": "testproject" }},
            "filter": { "term":  { "category": "invoice" }}
        }
    }}
```

Comment: Is this way better performance than a list of all documents in this category?

Comment: What do you mean by "a list of all documents in this category"?

Comment: a classic index table.

Comment: You mean create a separate index for each category? It really depends on your data, the type of queries you want to be able to do, and how you define performance (memory? speed? etc) whether separate indices, separate types or a field for distinguishing categories will be highest performing. However, term filters are extremely fast and results are cached so in general this solution will perform very well.